# how to find mis-spell words in bunch of files

Tags: shell, unix, grep, spell-checking

I have around 10k `java` files I need to find mis-spelled words in those `java` files for the strings which are in `double-quotes`

Following is giving me strings in `double-quotes`

`find . -name "*.java" -exec grep -Po '".*?"' {} \;`

But I do not know how to use `spell` on top of this.

Comment: I am not answering your question, but your find statement does not handle escaped quotes `\" ` the right way.

Comment: @user2799037 his `find` and `grep` look fine to me

Answer (score 1):

I have only available Linux and `ispell` so if you are not on Linux the following might not work for you (as is). If you just want to find mis-spelled words and get proposals listed then you could use

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep -Po '"([^"\\]|\\.)*"' {} \; \
| ispell -a -S
```

The `-a` selects pipe-mode, `-S` disables sorting which tends to list better replacements first.

If you want to fix the strings in-place, then you may want to use something like

```
TEMP=`mktemp`
find . -name "*.java" | xargs grep -l '"...*"' \
| xargs echo /usr/bin/ispell -F ./so20836228-java-deformatter.sh > $TEMP
source $TEMP
```

This generates spell-checking commands which use the following ispell Java "deformatter":

```
#!/bin/sh
# Experimental Java ispell deformatter: use at your own risk!
/bin/sed -e '1,$ {
# introduce per-character state
s/\(.\)/\1_/g
# mark string literals
s/"_\(\(\([^"\\]_\|\\_._\)\)*\)"_/"B\1"E/g
# wipe out chars before string literals
:b s/._\(.\)B/ B\1B/g ; t b
# wipe out chars after string literals
:e s/\(.\)E._/\1E E/g ; t e
# remove per-character state
s/\(.\)./\1/g
# get rid of escape sequences
s/\\./  /g
}'
```

Use this experimental deformatter at your own risk.
Backup files before you work on them.
(Errors in the deformatter may damage spell-checked files.
See ispell manual page:
*The program must produce exactly one character of output for each character of input, or ispell will lose synchronization and corrupt the output file.*
)